# Как максимально быстро рисовать тысячи TShape-ов?

Tags: delphi, vcl

У меня в программе нужно отображение большого количества шейпов с написанными на них текстом. Количество шейпов может быть до 20 тыс. Получится такая большая схема. Для быстроты работы хотелось бы реализовать свое подобие шейпа.

Я реализовала класс, в котором одним из полей был шейп обьект. После в методе paint я писала на нем текст. Но проблема в том что из-за вызова этого метода когда панель на которой создается шейп невидима, программа зацикливалась.

Итого. Нужно или понять как максимально быстро отображать быстро отображать эти шейпы с созданием надписи в методе паинт, или самой написать нечто подобное. Подскажите как быть? и может быть есть смысл сделать это на канве? У меня не получилось. Вернее не все прорисовывалось, и при сворачивании экрана у меня все стиралось. Рисовала в paintbox.

Answer (score 2):

Создать TBitmap нужного размера.

Перед началом сцены стереть его (TCanvas.FillRect)

Отрисовывать всё в него с помощью функций TCanvas.

Когда сцена закончена, вызвать перерисовку PaintBox (например, Refresh).

В OnPaint PaintBox-а выводить на него битмап.

(При перерисовке формы OnPaint будет вызван автоматически)

Comment: Спасибо) Я попробую. А это будет быстрее чем с шейпами?

Comment: А в чем заключается разница между тем чтобы рисовать в битмапе или рисовать в паинтбоксе? я просто не совсем понимаю как это решает проблему) Вы не могли бы обьяснить немного свое решение?

Comment: Да, несколько быстрее - не нужно создавать и обслуживать тысячи объектов.

Comment: Это называется двойная буферизация. Вывод производится только для законченной картинки, нет мерцания, не требуется постоянное обновление win-контролов.

Comment: Вы же уже столкнулись с тем, что PaintBox не хранит картинку (по сути это просто место на форме или другом контроле).

Comment: Тоесть, подытожим)  Мне нужно все мои махинации делать в битмапе а после перерисовывать на paintbox, так?) Спасибо вам огромное сразу)